# Custom ISO for offline install with UEFI + Legacy BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, bios

I have followed many articles, tutorials and forums over the internet and I cannot find nothing related to this:
I need to create a custom ISO of my current installation, which can be installed into UEFI and Legacy BIOS offline (no internet during installation).

However I can't manage to work on different settings which I create the ISO:

- Creating ISO on UEFI system can only install on UEFI systems offline
- -- Installing on BIOS Legacy system it fails to install bootloader (no bootloader installed)
- Creating ISO on Legacy BIOS can only install on Legacy BIOS systems offline.
- -- Installing on UEFI system it fails saying grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install
- Installing both with internet (online) works, but this is not desirable.

What am I missing? Is there any straightforward tutorial I could follow?

Comment: What we usually do is install the regular ISO and use a utility to repair the bootloader if necessary. With your method you also may need to repair the repairs. You may be unconsciously introducing a whole new layer of complexity with your method.

Comment: If what you want is to create 1 installer to use on several machines you will/might run into trouble too: not all EFI are equal on every machine. Hardware spefications of EFI leave room for tweaks. An installer is only guaranteed to work on the machine it was made on.

Comment: according to your comments, it would be impossible to do so. But how distros are distributed on ISO to be installed both on UEFI and BIOS + Legacy. If you download any Ubuntu amd64 iso, they will be able to install anywhere, without any issues. How do they do that?

Answer (score 0):

The FAI project provides an installation ISO for Ubuntu which can be used in UIFE and legacy BIOS enviroments. All packages needed are on the ISO, so no internet connection is needed.
Using FAI (Fully Automatic Installation) you can also customize the ISO to your local needs. There's also a web service for creating your own Ubuntu installation image, so you do not need to set up your own FAI server.